# tensorflow object detection API on windows using NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1650, CUDA 10.0

Tags: python

is it possible to install tensorflow object detection API on windows using NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1650, CUDA 10.0? i saw in tensorflow documentation that the version of cuda and cudnn used are 9.0 and 7.0 respectively. i am wondering, if it is possible to install using cuda 10.0. because, cuda 9.0 is not compatible with the driver installed on my computer

gaming

Comment: check the corresponding cudnn version for the installed cuda version.  You will be able to make it work.

Comment: yeah i am using cudnn 7.4.1